# quadratic rings of integers vs cubic rings of integers in number fields

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I would appreciate if someone could give me some clues about cubic $\mathbb{Z}$-rings of number fields.  So far I have only learned about quadratic rings and I would like to see if there are any similarities between these two structures.

Let  $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})\supset \mathbb{Q}$ be some quadratic field extension where $d\neq1$ and square-free. Then we know that this quadratic field extension creates sort of a ''living space'' for the ring of integers $\mathcal{O_{k}}$ of $K$
such that $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathcal{O_{k}}\subset K$. Now if:

$d\equiv 1 \pmod 4\Rightarrow \mathcal{O_{k}}=\mathbb{Z}\Bigl[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{d}\Bigr]$ ,with integral basis $\{1,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{d}\}$

$d\equiv 2,3 \pmod 4\Rightarrow \mathcal{O_{k}}=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$, with integral basis $\{1,\sqrt{d}\}$

An example of such quadratic ring can be $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ or $\mathbb{Z}[\epsilon]$ where $\epsilon=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}},\mathbb{Z}[(\sqrt{2}]$etc.

If we now consider a cubic extension :

Let  $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d})\supset \mathbb{Q}$ where $d\neq1$ and cubic-free. Then I have read that we will also have a ring of integers inside the number field.

How does such cubic $\mathbb{Z}$-ring look like? How it is generated? Does it also have integral basis? Are there any simple examples of  such rings?
Or can someone recommend a relevant literature on the topic?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes. The ring of interest is the ring of algebraic integers ${\cal O}_K$ = the integral closure of $\Bbb{Z}$ in $K$ (roots of monic polynomials with integer coefficients). It is always a free abelian group of rank three, and thus has an integral basis. Look up any book on algebraic number theory. Mind you, not all cubic fields are obtained by adjoining a cube root.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: The problem is that each book on algebraic number theory only presents quadratic rings. Unfortunately there is nothing about cubic Z-rings. I would like to find some information about indices in cubic rings as well.

Comment: Heidi, if you will look on the right of the web page, there are about 10 links to MSE questions that the software thinks are related to your question. The first title is "On determining the ring of integers of a cubic number field" If you click to go to such a question, there is another list of "Related" questions there, and so on.